# Google Analytics notifications

Tags: ios, mobile, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, mobile-analytics

I am looking for a way to get notified by an email about critical issues in mobile apps. Currently, Google Analytics (with firebase or itself) is the best solution to suit my tasks: crash reports, usage and custom events tracking. But if there is something critically wrong with an app, can I get notified without logging into GA administration panel?

I was looking for answers in documentation, administration panel, forums. The answers were misleading, because it is not easy to formulate a question and do not get a bunch of articles about remote messaging that google provides.

I was trying to contact google itself, but it is not providing support for free. You need to have adwords or other paid business tools I do not have and need.

Is there a way to solve my tasks in GA scope or I need to integrate other tracking service? Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure with Google Analytics, but I have been using Crashlytics which is now a part of Fabric and also a part of google Firebase. You can setup the app in Fabric and then download its mobile app. 
As soon as there is a crash, you get a notification on the app on your mobile with access to logs.
https://try.crashlytics.com/

Comment: @kapsym Thanks for suggestion, I will look in Fabric direction. Do you know if it has custom events/screen tracking features? Can I be notified about them as well?

Comment: It has both custom events and screen tracking feature as a part of Fabric. I am not sure of the notification about them as i have not set any notifications for them but you can try.